# $.post request inside a $.get request

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I want to get the response of a post request and fill a  in another page with what I've got but I didn't work.

I appreciate any help or a hint to better think of that problem.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            $('img').click(function () {
                alert(this.id);
                var id = this.id;

                $.get('testpost.php', null, function (text) {
                    $.post('testcurlserver.php', {'id': id}, function (data) {
                        $(text).find(#containerr).html(data);
                    });
                });
            });
```

here is the testpost.php

```
<html>


        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <body>    



        <script type="text/javascript">

        $.post('testcurlserver.php', {'id': id}, function (data) {

                    $('#content').html(data);
                });


            </script>


        <div id="containerr" style ="border: 1px solid red;">

        </div>
</body>        
</html>
```

Comment: Did the get call return data?

Comment: do a `console.log` inside the `$.get` to make sure that works first

Comment: what kind of data is being returned? Is it JSON or plain text?